# How to show text in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a table and I want to show there some text; but I can't, I don't know why. My app is a view-based app, and I don't want to change it for a Table View Controller. Here's the code:

```
.h 

{
 NSArray *array;
 IBOutlet UITableView *table;
}


.m


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Please help me because I'm trying to solve this and I don't know what's wrong, why the Table doesn't show the array!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you connected your dataSource and delegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly haven't connected your datasource and delegates properly in IB.

Your UIViewController needs to implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource, and you need to then connect it to your UITableView (table) as such in Interface Builder.

For details, read through [Apple's documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW11).

Comment: Ok! I read it and it works now! Thank you for answering my silly questions!

Answer (score 0):

On your .H file are you using this interfaces `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>?`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you've never ever created  single cell.  The call you make dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier  only recycles cells you've already created.  Add this code after the dequeueResusable... line:

```
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```